# Information and Settings Collected from a PC Connected to a Web Server

Tags: privacy, webserver, vpn

1- What are the information and settings collected from my pc when I connect to a website server?

2- When I connect through a VPN, Could the website server detect a mismatch between my new location and some of my PC’s settings related to the real location like time and time zone?

3- As a conclusion, Should I change some of my PC’s settings in order to match my new IP?

Comment: See https://panopticlick.eff.org/